# Unable to install or build ghc-mod or other packages with Stack

Tags: haskell, archlinux, haskell-stack

I am trying to set up a development environment for Haskell on my Arch Linux machine.

I have read about the static linking fiasco which has made Arch and Haskell a pain.

I [manually install stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#manual-download_2) and run:

```
stack setup
```

Then, I make a project with:

```
stack new hello
```

After this, I run:

```
stack build ghc-mod
```

I add these to my extra dependencies:

```
extra-deps:         
     - Cabal-1.24.2.0
     - base-4.9.1.0
     - cabal-helper-0.7.3.0
     - djinn-ghc-0.0.2.3
     - extra-1.5.3
     - ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3.3
     - haskell-src-exts-1.19.1
     - hlint-2.0.15
     - monad-journal-0.7.2
     - optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0
     - temporary-1.2.1.1
```

And then, I run `stack build ghc-mod` again, and get this error, which I am stuck at:

```
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: ghc-boot-8.4.3
Possible candidates: ghc-boot-8.4.1, ghc-boot-8.4.2.
```

This also happens no matter which package I try to install. I add the extradeps, and then I get this message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ghc-mod doesn't support the latest version of GHC. There are multiple questions about this already, e.g.:

- [Can not install GHC-Mod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51293944/369198)
- [stack install ghc-mod fails with dependencies conflicts on OSX 10.13.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50948485/369198)

Comment: It’s not just ghc-mod. I said that it’s any package.

Comment: You haven't demonstrated any other packages giving that error. Try removing the `extra-deps` and trying again.